# Creating an object that could be passed in as parameters for swiper JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, variables, swiper.js

I'm trying to create a swiper instance from user input, for example:

A user inputs a string:

```
swiper-direction-horizontal swiper-effect-slide swiper-speed-300
```

or something similar.


Then using javascript/jquery I could take that string and convert it into a variable and use it to create the swiper:

```
var swiperParams = {direction: horizontal, effect: slide, speed: 300}
var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', swiperParams);
```

What would be the best way to do this? (performance is important)

Comment: "or something similar." The answer really depends on this. So depending of the input there are sure better solutions. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out a way to do it, thanks nonetheless.
Here's a code snippet https://jsfiddle.net/z5pgarnq/10/, if someone has a better solution I'll be thankful for sharing.

```
var input = 'swiper-direction-horizontal swiper-speed-300 swiper-loop-true';
var array = input.split(' ');
var params = {};
var value = '';
for (i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  if (!array[i].indexOf('swiper')) {
    value = array[i].split('-')[2];
    if ($.isNumeric(value)) {
      value = parseInt(value, 10);
    } else if (value === 'true') {
      value = (value === 'true');
    }
    params[array[i].split('-')[1]] = value;
  }
}
console.log(params);
//console:
//Object { loop: true, speed: 300, direction: "horizontal" }
```